# strange marker info messages from maven dependency plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

how I can get rid of these messages?

> [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:unpack-dependencies (jetty-classpath) @ scmapi ---
>   isMarkerOlder:
>     artifact1 = .../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.1.1.v20140108/jetty-io-9.1.1.v20140108.jar
>     marker    = .../src/maven-intermediate/scmapi/dependency-maven-plugin-markers/org.eclipse.jetty-jetty-io-jar-9.1.1.v20140108.marker
>       artifact1 lastModified: 1398992691000
>       marker lastModified: 1398992691000
>   < false = marker older than artifact?
>   isMarkerOlder:
>     artifact1 = .../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.1.1.v20140108/jetty-webapp-9.1.1.v20140108.jar
>     marker    = .../src/maven-intermediate/scmapi/dependency-maven-plugin-markers/org.eclipse.jetty-jetty-webapp-jar-9.1.1.v20140108.marker
>       artifact1 lastModified: 1398992692000
>       marker lastModified: 1398992692000
>   < false = marker older than artifact?

Note that the `artifact1 lastModified: 1398992692000` value and the `marker lastModified: 1398992692000` are exactly the same. Which contradicts the error message `marker older than artifact`.

Note also that if you google: "marker older than artifact" you could find that a lot of people have the same `"[info]"` messages reported in their builds.

Comment: Can you show the pom file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have checked in your marker files in Perforce by mistake. It says that, for an artifact like this one

```
 artifact1 = .../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.1.1.v20140108/jetty-io-9.1.1.v20140108.jar
```

It has a marker file here

```
 marker = .../Perforce/scmapi/src/maven-intermediate/scmapi/dependency-maven-plugin-markers/org.eclipse.jetty-jetty-io-jar-9.1.1.v20140108.marker
```

The artifact is in a .m2 repository directory, which looks normal, but the reference to Perforce on the marker path makes me a bit anxious.

Check to see if you may have marker files under revision control by mistake and subsequently get rid of it.

Then you should be able to clear and update dependencies, for example like:

```
mvn -U dependency:go-offline
```

And the problem should subsequently go away.

Comment: no, I do not have marker files submitted in perforce

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, what I did was remove the content which was under /target in my project and the recompile all, the issue was gone with that, hope that helps.

I suspicious that the problem in my case was because I was using maven to solve dependencies but also the IDE tool, probably that affected my dependencies